# timetable scheduling using multidimensional priority table

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, timetable

I need a solution to schedule tasks on given dates for timetable scheduling. It is based on each user's vote. I have a table that contains number of votes for the task for the date:

Tasks: {"A","B","C","D","E"}, 
Dates: {"1 Jan","2 Jan","5 Jan","7 Jan","10 Jan"},
Total users: 16

```
              A      B     C      D      E
  =============================================

  1-Jan  |    6      3     1      4      2

  2-Jan  |    1      3     4      6      2

  5-Jan  |    2      3     3      1      7

  7-Jan  |    6      1     2      3      4

  10-Jan |    1      6     5      3      1
```

For example, on 1-Jan, task A has 6 votes, task B has 3 votes, etc.

I need to schedule only one task for one date.

How to schedule tasks? Can anybody help?

Comment: It seems the number of votes cast each month remains constant (16). Anyway, given a solution (Task i, Date j) ... The idea is to maximize the sum of the votes cast on Date j to Task i. _Dynamic Programming_ seems a good way to go

Comment: What is the objective function? What are you trying to optimize? (max or min).